# How to show a method is 0-stable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to show that the method $y_{j+1} = y_j + h\big( \theta f(t_j, y_j) + (1 - \theta) f(t_{j+1}, y_{j+1}) \big)$ is 0-stable.

I looked at the [first page of this document](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~peirce/M405_607E_Lecture%2017.pdf) to try to figure it out. I think I have to come up with $P_N(\theta)$ and find the roots of it. But I had no idea what

$$P_N(\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^N a_k \theta^k$$

meant. What is $N$, $a_k$, and $\theta^k$, and how do I find it from this $N$ step method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your method in the form of the first equation labelled (*) in the document you are linked to. This will give you $a_k$ and $N$. The variable $\theta$ is the variable in the polynomial, which is different from the $\theta$ you have in your method, so to avoid confusion you should rename one of them. Finally, $\theta^k$ is simply $\theta$ to the power $k$.

Added later: $f_{j+k}$ in equation (*) is short-hand for $f(t_{j+k}, y_{j+k})$.

Comment: How? I came up with $$h \sum_{k=0}^1 (k + (-1)^k x) f(t_{j+k}, y){j+k}$$ (renaming $\theta$ to $x$). I don't think this is right because I don't have $y_j$.